# Mirotik : Client from interface 1 cant access client from interface 2

Tags: firewall, nat, mikrotik

I have a mikrotik here.

Both interface 1 and 2 have same network (10.10.30.0) and dhcp pool.

I can ping any client on interface 1 from mikrotik and also any client on interface 2. But I cant use to ping any client on interface 2 from any client interface 1. It seems each interface cannot communicate.

I have 3 interface enabled currently.

This is the current IP configuration :

```
PC : 10.10.10.3/24 - interface1
ADSL router : 10.10.30.2/25 - interface2
WD My Cloud : 10.10.30.200/25 - interface3
```

Please help

Comment: You have conflicting subnets. Resolving that is your first step to getting this resolved.

Comment: @EEAA : Ok thanks. Now I already change the subnet.

Answer (score -3):

Solved.

I just create a NAT in firewall panel.
Action : masquerade
Chain : srcnat
Out interface : Eth3 (one of my ethernet interface)

Comment: This is not a solution. As EEAA mentioned you have conflicting subnets. You need to create a bridge, assign all ethernet ports (that have the same subnet) to it and then add the IP address on the bridge interface. What you've done is a bodge at best and will certainly cause you problems in the long run.